# Как скачать страницу после выполнения js

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin

Мне нужно скачать страницу после **ПОЛНОЙ ЗАГРУЗКИ, ИМЕННО  в ANDROID (JAVA/KOTLIN), Спасибо**
(Именно в коде как это будет выглядеть )

Comment: Используйте селениум - виртуальный браузер. Простого способа сделать такое нет

Comment: phantomjs в помощь

Comment: Про селениум  и  phantomjs  я знаю  , я не могу найти именно примера, в коде не совсем понятно

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097352/how-can-i-parse-dynamic-content-from-a-web-page Попробуйте поискать тут

Comment: Всем спасибо ,  буду разбираться